# Blender equivalent to zbrush's polish-option

Tags: modeling, sculpting

i recently followed this zbrush-tutorial on sculpting a character.

https://pixologic.com/zclassroom/lesson/the-eyes-part-2

During this tutorial the tutor made use of the polish-option.

(ca.4:50 i think it might be that one:
http://docs.pixologic.com/user-guide/3d-modeling/hard-surface/polish-features/  )

It seems that this feature preserves hard edges, while smoothing the surface. Is there something similar in blender?[image][image]

Comment: The way that I know to do this is to first using crease tool with ditypo followed by pinch and smooth, both without ditypo. Maybe there is addons that can help but as far as I know blender by itself don't have this tool.